# Primefaces p:autocomplete component doesnot works under dialog box

Tags: jsf-2, autocomplete, primefaces

I am using primefaces p:autocomplete component (primefaces version 3.0), its working fine , but I am getting 2 issues with it.

First is when I am puuting p:autocomplete component inside dialog box ,and if a user gets suggestions after some typing keywords,  it  stuckes, neither we can type anymore nor we can use backspace .

Second is p:autocomplete component suggestions are case sensitive.But user should get always  suggestions whether he didnt used capital letters.

As a e.g: if a name is stored in database as "John" with capital letter, but if a user type 'jo' with small case letter he should get suggestion as a "John".

How can I solve  it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a specific answer for your first part. Possibly a PF bug. Is it just the autocomplete that sticks? Does the whole browser hang? Are you able to use other controls on the page?

As for the case sensitivity, you would control that in your autocomplete method on the backing bean. If you want to ignore case, use .toLowerCase(), .toUpperCase(), .equalsIgnoreCase() in your compare.

Comment: Are you using a modal dialogue box? If so, there is a bug that sounds like what you are describing here: http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=4005 Looks like they fixed it for PF3.3.1.

Comment: yes I am using same modal dialog box here, so is there any workaround for it?

Comment: The changelog indicated that it was fixed in the latest release (3.3.1). I don't know that there is a work around other than to upgrade to 3.3.1.